# How to run docker command: 'docker machine ls' within Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

How to run docker command: 'docker machine ls' within Jenkins?

I need to run the following command within Jenkins:

```
docker machine ls
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use pipelines or base on the plugins?

Comment: its just a simple jenkins job which would pull the latest code from Git and then trigger the tests.

Comment: How the tests are run? With the plugin or bash command?

Comment: via Maven invoker

Comment: what you trying to achieve? Jenkins has docker plugin which can be use to work with docker. Also refer https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ for various examples.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link

### Some step guideline available

http://docs.docker.com/v17.09/machine/examples/ocean/#step-3-use-machine-to-create-the-droplet

Comment: thanks for the comment and link, can I not simply run the above script as a shell command?

For example the following works: sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' webDriver-chrome